# ngModel return undefined in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two drop down in html.
First dropdown is giving the selected value but the second dropdown is return as undefined.

component.html

```
<form class="form row">
<div class="inputGroup inputGroup--medium">
        <label class="inputGroup__label is-required">Product</label>
        <div class="selectWrapper">
          <select id="selectProduct"  class="inputGroup__select" [(ngModel)]="selectedProduct"
            (ngModelChange)="setProductVersion($event)"[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
            <option selected value="" disabled>Select Product</option>
            <option *ngFor="let product of Products" [value]="product.name">
              {{ product.name}}
            </option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
 <div class="inputGroup inputGroup--medium">
        <label class="inputGroup__label is-required">Product Version</label>
        <div class="selectWrapper">
          <select id="selectProductVersion" class="inputGroup__select"           
          [(ngModel)]="selectedProductVersion" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
          <option selected value="" disabled>Select Product Version</option>
            <option *ngFor="let pVersion of ProductsVersion" [value]="pVersion.name">
              {{ pVersion.productVersion}}
            </option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

component.ts

```
 selectedProduct:any;
    selectedProductVersion:any;

 setProductVersion(event){
  const filteredResult = this.AllProductsVersion.filter(x=> x.productName ==this.selectedProduct);
  this.ProductsVersion=filteredResult;
 }
```

this.AllProductsVersion is Json data. and i'm able to set the product version based on selected product using this function.

selectedProduct is giving the result whatever is selected in dropdown but selectedProductVersion is giving as undefined.

Comment: What exactly you want to do?? like what is the functionality of this?

Comment: i have to post the selectedProduct and selectedProductVesion to the API. hence selected values are required.

Comment: So is second dropdowns' values are based on the selected value of first dropdown?

Comment: yes. second dropdown values are based on first dropdown. so i'm calling the  (ngModelChange)="setProductVersion($event)" to set the values in second dropdown.

Comment: You should share some typescript as well.

Comment: ok! can you show me the code of that function..?

Comment: added the function code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing this:

```
 <option selected value="" disabled>Select Product Version</option>
            <option *ngFor="let pVersion of ProductsVersion" [value]="pVersion.productVersion">
              {{ pVersion.productVersion}}
            </option>
```

Comment: i'm using the correct variable.this.ProductsVersion will return the filteredResult which i'm iterating in html ngFor loop.

Comment: Okk so when would be the data comes in selectedProductVersion variable.?

Comment: when the second dropdata data is selected [(ngModel)]="selectedProductVersion" this should save the selection and assign it  to selectedProductVersion variable. however for firstdrop down it's working fine.

Comment: Okk, will you be able to show data in second dropdown list for selection?

Comment: yes. in second dropdown data is coming based on first dropdown selection. but i'm not able to get the selected data from second drop down to selectedProductVersion  variable

Comment: try using event in second dropdown (change)="onChange($event.target.value)" and check if selected options value showing or not..

Comment: it is still giving undefined

Comment: what is the log of $event.target.value)??

Comment: onChange(event){
  console.log((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value);
} this is giving un defined

Comment: yes, its array which contains the product version

Comment: can you show me that dropdown list and array console...??

Comment: {id: 2, productName: "Product1", productVersion: "V1"}
{id: 3, productName: "Product1", productVersion: "V2"} this is array console and same are listed in dropdown as well.

Comment: Yess I think I know the issue... answer has been edited.. try new updated answer..!!

Comment: OMG ! this is wat i was missing in value and struggling since yesterday. thanks a lot for the taking interest and pointing to the issue

Comment: You're  welcome! variable showing undefined is because there is no name key exist in the array as you have just copy pasted your code! ;)